# does velocity have a method which returns template by passing String as argument?

Tags: java, velocity

I have a requirement in which i have a String which contains file content, i have to create a template of that string using velocity. is there any method in velocity which takes string as input and returns template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I made a template out of a String:

```
        RuntimeServices runtimeServices = RuntimeSingleton.getRuntimeServices();

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(stringValue);
        SimpleNode node = runtimeServices.parse(reader, "Template name");
        Template template = new Template();
        template.setRuntimeServices(runtimeServices);
        template.setData(node);
        template.initDocument();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Velocity.evaluate()` is what you want. From the example in the [docs](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/developer-guide.html):

```
public class Example2
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        /* first, we init the runtime engine.  Defaults are fine. */

        Velocity.init();

        /* lets make a Context and put data into it */

        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

        context.put("name", "Velocity");
        context.put("project", "Jakarta");

        /* lets render a template */

        StringWriter w = new StringWriter();

        Velocity.mergeTemplate("testtemplate.vm", context, w );
        System.out.println(" template : " + w );

        /* lets make our own string to render */

        String s = "We are using $project $name to render this.";
        w = new StringWriter();
        Velocity.evaluate( context, w, "mystring", s );
        System.out.println(" string : " + w );
    }
}
```